# How to set one keyboard event at a time?

Tags: jquery, input, keyboard

I have this function here

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
        if (e.which == 39) {
            goRight();
        }
        if (e.which == 37) {
            goLeft();
        };
    });
```

And I want that: if I press the right or the left arrow keys, calling any of my functions (goRight or goLeft), I can only execute the other key pressing action after the function do it's job. What I want is similar to the stop() function to animations. Because when I press left/right very quickly all my margin get bugged.

The goRight function is this

```
function goRight(){
                if(!$('.livin').hasClass('blog') ){
            $('#contentGeral .containerConteudo ul').stop().animate({marginLeft:'-=800'},function(){
                    removeClasses();
                    addClasses();
                });
            }
            else{
                $('#contentGeral .containerConteudo ul').stop().animate({marginLeft:'0'}, function(){
                    removeClasses();
                    addClasses();
                    });
            }
    }
```

The goLeft is analogous.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: have you tried `.stop(true,true)` in the functions

Comment: In the animate functions or like "e.stop(true,true).which" or even like this "stop(true,true).goLeft();" ?

Comment: Nevermind, stop(true,true) in the animation did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `.stop(true,true)` made this work. Thanks 3nigma for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an enable boolean on it? It would look something like this:

```
var enable = 1;
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.which == 39) {
        if(enable == 1){
            enable = 0;
            goRight();
            enable = 1;
        }
    }
    if (e.which == 37) {
        if(enable == 1){
            enable = 0;
            goLeft();
            enable = 1;
        }
    };
});
```

That's just a shot in the dark though. I'm not exactly sure what your problem is, hope that helps!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, the idea is good but it think it didn't work because placing the boolean after the function call does not guarantee that the enable variable will be set as 1 after the function is fully executed, and that's what I need. I need a similar solution but only call enable = 1 after executing "goRight"

I tried even putting the "enable = 1" inside the goRight and goLeft, at it's bottom, but it didn't work as well

if i press left/right quickly, stuff like an average value between the right margin-left appears